# How to use Google Maps Utility Library in eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps, utility

I have just seen [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb2X9IjjZpM) in youtube.

I want use BubbleIconFactory in map v2, but BubbleIconFactory is showing as deprecated in eclipse.

I don't how to use [this library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you look into the source code - this class does nothing and indeed deprecated :)
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/BubbleIconFactory.java

```
package com.google.maps.android.ui;

/**
 * Use {@link IconGenerator} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class BubbleIconFactory {
}
```

I suppose you need to use equivalent to this class: [IconGenerator](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.java)